# Oracle SQL -- how to delete partial duplicates with a preference

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Could you please help me in deleting duplicates (partial) from table? I have a table containing 5 columns. And in this table I have duplicates -- but only 4 columns are the same and one of the columns (field5) is different. That is:

```
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5
A1 A2 A3 A4 103
A1 A2 A3 A4 3
```

So, for a duplicate, 4 columns/fields are the same, except the 5th one. And I want to delete the row containing number "103", that's, a higher number. How can I achieve this?

If this was a normal duplicate, I would just use max(rowid) and remove that row. But now this could delete the row containing lower number instead of the higher number.

One method that I can think of is creating a new table containing rows which are duplicate and Field5 has a higher number from this table. Then deleting rows from original table by comparing it to this new table. But that seems not so good solution to me -- especially if the original table is big, this might take long time.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to keep a record for each combinations of `F1,F2,F3,F4` and delete the rest.

Try this:

```
    DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ROWID IN 
    (SELECT ROWID FROM 
        (SELECT ROWID, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY F1,F2,F3,F4 ORDER BY F5) RN 
           FROM TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE RN<>1);
```

Comment: That would raise ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc. But, would work if you remove ROWNUM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post! This one works perfect. Previous post raised error as specified by Littlefoot. If I could select, this would be the best solution for me
 :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SQL> select * from test order by f1, f5;

F1 F2 F3 F4         F5
-- -- -- -- ----------
a1 a2 a3 a4          3
a1 a2 a3 a4         50  --> delete
a1 a2 a3 a4        103  --> delete
b1 b2 b3 b4          2
b1 b2 b3 b4        200  --> delete
c1 c2 c3 c4          1

6 rows selected.

SQL> delete from test t
  2        where rowid not in (select rowid
  3                              from test t1
  4                             where     t1.f1 = t.f1
  5                                   and t1.f2 = t.f2
  6                                   and t1.f3 = t.f3
  7                                   and t1.f4 = t.f4
  8                                   and t1.f5 =
  9                                          (select min (t2.f5)
 10                                             from test t2
 11                                            where     t2.f1 = t.f1
 12                                                  and t2.f2 = t.f2
 13                                                  and t2.f3 = t.f3
 14                                                  and t2.f4 = t.f4));

3 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from test order by f1, f5;

F1 F2 F3 F4         F5
-- -- -- -- ----------
a1 a2 a3 a4          3
b1 b2 b3 b4          2
c1 c2 c3 c4          1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Littlefoot!  Your answer is great! and thanks for pointing out the issue on the first post. I didn't know this could be solved by the stuff/concepts I know myself :)  so, thanks pointing out such solution. Only drawback for this solution would be having a bit too much lines when there are many columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I normally just do this:

```
delete demo
where  rowid in
       ( select lead(rowid) over (partition by f1, f2, f3, f4 order by f5) as next_rowid
         from   demo );
```

That is, delete every "next" row in order of `f5` within its `(f1, f2, f3, f4)` group.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's an interesting solution. I actually had a doubt first, but looks like it works as expected.